# Why should one study?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

At school, a student seems to learn many things that will most likely never be specifically used in their lifetime. So why should they study it at all?

Comment: One obvious reason is to learn how to learn. Practicing the skill of learning itself is often far more valuable then any specific content one might learn.

Comment: Hello! I voted to close, as did others, because while this is a question in the philosophical sense related to wisdom, it's not sufficiently technical and focused. If you haven't had a chance, review the site FAQ or pop over onto the meta part of this site to seek clarification.

Comment: All why-questions are philosophical sense related to wisdom. Or all why-questions are philosophical problems, if you irritated with childish question - it is same you say "nope", when they trying to study "wisdom". And every time you say nope, you say it to self -that is only reason to say nope for why-questions.

Comment: If why-quest's answers determinate on any instructions or  bureaucrat's decisions and this is call "phylosofy"  or "wisdom" i really have to burn this tower.

Comment: Each piece of knowledge is like a tool in a toolbox. The more tools you have, the more you can do and having the right tools for the job makes life easier.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of early, pre-university, education is to provide as broad a foundation as possible because it's uncertain what a student will excel in. It's kinda like a shotgun approach - expose children and young adults to as many subjects as possible and find out which one of them clicks. The side-effect of this tehcnique is people complaining of having to learn stuff they don't actually use as adults.

There are mechanisms in place for *gifted children* but they're STEM biased. A student who's a history prodigy has to plod along with the rest of his peers, but one who's got a knack for numbers is permitted to skips grades (in math).

Comment: +1 for a good answer. I wonder though, *"a student who's a history prodigy has to plod along with the rest of his peers"* might be true generally, but do you think some history prodigies may also be good at STEM subjects, and say, excel at looking at the engineering within pyramid building structure and form (the geometry, the structural strengths and weakness, how they were built etc.) as an example?

Comment: @ChrisRogers, I concur - there's an overlap of skills.

Answer (score 2):

People study to get a concentration skill. Studying process not depends on interest concernment only. One has to be able concentrate at interesting and at boring too. Study it is close to meditative practice study old mean to "read a book or writings intently or meditatively."
Child without concentration skill  it is attention deficit hyperactivity disorder or ADHD.

If you have only usefull things you don't know how to use it. It need both definitions a usefull and a useless.
Studying process it is "a wheat from the chaff" skill. But one need to self know what is the wheat and what is the chaff.

And second base of studying is the newest neurobiology meaning. When you study something you get not the information, but the formed pattern. This pattern can be used to another kind of information. Studying process construct the house of knowledge, not only storage for information(but some formal learning methodics do storage only, test examined system for example). So, study to look beyond the information limits.

Comment: I love your writing style, which I don't see a lot of, unfortunately. While some subjects require information and checking the accuracy of that information, the actual act of studying also keeps concentration strong. Studying what you were putting across certainly gave my mind a workout. A rolling stone gathers no moss just as a studying person does not get rusty in thought.